# How to not overlap bars of separate but related datasets in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

Is there a simple way with the bar function to get 2 datasets side-by-side and not overlapping?

```
dataset1 = (num1, num2, num3, num4)
bar(dataset1);
```

I get 4 bars in a plot.
Now let's get...

```
dataset2 = (num5, num6, num7, num8)
bar (dataset1);
hold on;
bar (dataset2);
```

There are 8 bars, sure, but dataset2 overlaps dataset1.  I want them to appear side-by-side, adjacent, with spaces between their little group and the next two values that are bars (simply, 4 sets of 2 bars).  This should be simple because the datasets are on the same scale....
Does this make sense?  I tried doing something that Shai suggested in a different thread, but merely subtracting or adding a value to dataset 1 or 2 during the bar function (bar dataset1+.5) doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `bar` plot should do the trick with `dataset1` and `dataset2` embedded in a matrix.

The following code

```
dataset1 = rand(4,1);
dataset2 = rand(4,1)+1;

bar([dataset1 dataset2])
legend({'data1';'data2'});
```

produces

[image]